# Fatal Python error: pycurl: libcurl link-time version is older than compile-time version

Tags: package-management, yum, python

When updating yum via sudo on our (Amazon Linux) server, I get the following error:

```
Fatal Python error: pycurl: 
libcurl link-time version is older than compile-time version
```

I find the following libcurl libraries on the system:

```
/usr/lib/libcurl.so.4.3.0
/usr/lib/libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.3.0

/usr/local/zend/lib/libcurl.so.4.2.0
/usr/local/zend/lib/libcurl.so -> libcurl.so.4.2.0
/usr/local/zend/lib/libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.2.0
```

I have tried various things, like this [Oracle blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/debugging_shared_library_problems_a):

```
python
>>> import pycurl
dlopen("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pycurl.so", 2);

ldd /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pycurl.so
libcurl.so.4 => /usr/local/zend/lib/libcurl.so.4 (0xb7714000)
rpm -q /usr/local/zend/lib/libcurl.so.4
package /usr/local/zend/lib/libcurl.so.4 is not installed
```

To be honest I don't have any idea what to do now, even if this info is useful. The only explanation I can give is that the wrong libcurl is used, but I don't think it's wise to change symlinks or just experiment.

**How can I get the right libcurl working?**